# Insert lines in a file from an other file lines in Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I would copy lines from a file `/tmp/test1` to a file `/tmp/test2`
the `/tmp/test1` contains:

```
argument1
argument2
@test1
@test2
@test3
```

the `/tmp/test2` contains:

```
argument1.1
argument2192
@example
@test2
@example1
```

So my main goal is to insert every line that doesn't exist in `/tmp/test2` from file `/tmp/test1`
and that the line added must be added at the end of the last line which is containing the same begin of line: `^[[:alpha:]]` and `^@`, so `/tmp/test2` should look like this:

```
argument1.1
argument2192
argument1
argument2
@example
@test2
@example1
@test1
@test3
```

I created this playbook but it doesn't do what i am looking for:

```
                  - name: check test1 content
                    command: cat /tmp/test1
                    register: tmp_content


                  - name: insert line
                    lineinfile:
                      path: /tmp/test2
                      line: '{{item}}'
                      insertafter: "^@*"
                    loop: "{{tmp_content.stdout_lines}}"
```

Comment: have you tried rewriting those `@` lines to be `{{ lookup("file", ...) }}` and then using `copy: { content: "{{ that_inline_jinja }}}", ...` or an actual `template:` invocation using the same trick?

Comment: Lookup plugin is not an option as the files are located in remote hosts, yes jinja template is a great option i will try with it

Comment: For remote files you can [`fetch`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html) or [`slurp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1) "Insert every line that doesn't exist in /tmp/test2 from file /tmp/test1"***

***2) "The line added must be added at the end of the last line which is containing the same beginning."***

A: The task below does the job. If the first character is `@` the line is inserted at the end of the file. Otherwise, the line is inserted before the first line starting with `@`. The parameters [*insertafter*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-insertafter) and [*insertbefore*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-insertbefore) may not be used together.  The negative options [*omit*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) make the parameters *insertafter* and *insertbefore* mutually exclusive

```yaml
    - name: insert line
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/test2
        line: "{{ item }}"
        insertafter: "{{ (item.0 == '@')|ternary('EOF', omit) }}"
        insertbefore: "{{ (item.0 != '@')|ternary('^@.*$', omit) }}"
        firstmatch: true
      loop: "{{ tmp_content.stdout_lines }}"
```

---

Notes

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: check test1 content
      command: cat /tmp/test1
      register: tmp_content
      changed_when: false
    - name: insert line
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/test2
        line: "{{ item }}"
        insertafter: "{{ (item.0 == '@')|ternary('EOF', omit) }}"
        insertbefore: "{{ (item.0 != '@')|ternary('^@.*$', omit)}}"
        firstmatch: true
      loop: "{{ tmp_content.stdout_lines }}"
```

The playbook is idempotent. See the output of the [*diff_mode*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#attribute-diff_mode) below

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --diff

...

TASK [insert line] *************************************************
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 argument1.1
 argument2192
+argument1
 @example
 @test2
 @example1

changed: [localhost] => (item=argument1)
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
 argument1.1
 argument2192
 argument1
+argument2
 @example
 @test2
 @example1

changed: [localhost] => (item=argument2)
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -5,3 +5,4 @@
 @example
 @test2
 @example1
+@test1

changed: [localhost] => (item=@test1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=@test2)
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -6,3 +6,4 @@
 @test2
 @example1
 @test1
+@test3

changed: [localhost] => (item=@test3)
```

---

- Brute force option

Read the files

```yaml
    - command: cat /tmp/test1
      register: test1
    - command: cat /tmp/test2
      register: test2
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
l1_alpha: "{{ test1.stdout_lines|select('match', '^[^@].*$') }}"
l1_glyph: "{{ test1.stdout_lines|select('match', '^@.*$') }}"
l2_alpha: "{{ test2.stdout_lines|select('match', '^[^@].*$') }}"
l2_glyph: "{{ test2.stdout_lines|select('match', '^@.*$') }}"
l1_alpha_diff: "{{ l1_alpha|difference(l2_alpha) }}"
l1_glyph_diff: "{{ l1_glyph|difference(l2_glyph) }}"
result: "{{ l2_alpha + l1_alpha_diff + l2_glyph + l1_glyph_diff }}"
```

This gives the expected result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for line in result %}
          {{ line }}
          {% endfor %}
```

```yaml
  msg: |-
    argument1.1
    argument2192
    argument1
    argument2
    @example
    @test2
    @example1
    @test1
    @test3
```

Write it to a file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test2
        content: |
          {% for line in result %}
          {{ line }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```
shell> cat /tmp/test2
argument1.1
argument2192
argument1
argument2
@example
@test2
@example1
@test1
@test3
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    l1_alpha: "{{ test1.stdout_lines|select('match', '^[^@].*$') }}"
    l1_glyph: "{{ test1.stdout_lines|select('match', '^@.*$') }}"
    l2_alpha: "{{ test2.stdout_lines|select('match', '^[^@].*$') }}"
    l2_glyph: "{{ test2.stdout_lines|select('match', '^@.*$') }}"
    l1_alpha_diff: "{{ l1_alpha|difference(l2_alpha) }}"
    l1_glyph_diff: "{{ l1_glyph|difference(l2_glyph) }}"
    result: "{{ l2_alpha + l1_alpha_diff + l2_glyph + l1_glyph_diff }}"
    
  tasks:
    - command: cat /tmp/test1
      register: test1
      changed_when: false
    - command: cat /tmp/test2
      register: test2
      changed_when: false
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test2
        content: |
          {% for line in result %}
          {{ line }}
          {% endfor %}
```

The playbook is idempotent.