# insert files lines into another depending regex filter in Ansible

Tags: python, regex, linux, ansible, yaml

I would copy lines from a file `/tmp/test1` to a file `/tmp/test2`
the `/tmp/test1` contains:

```
+ : argument1 : ALL
+ : argument2 : ALL
+ : @test1 : ALL
+ : @test2 : ALL
+ : @test3 : ALL
```

the `/tmp/test2` contains:

```
+ : argument1.1 : ALL
+ : argument2192 : ALL
+ : @example : ALL
+ : @test2 : ALL
+ : @example1 : ALL
```

So my main goal is to insert every line that doesn't exist in `/tmp/test2` from file `/tmp/test1`
and that the line added must be added at the end of the last line which is containing the same beginning after `+ :` : `^[[:alpha:]]` and `^@`, so `/tmp/test2` should look like this:

```
+ : argument1.1  : ALL
+ : argument2192 : ALL
+ : argument1 : ALL
+ : argument2 : ALL
+ : @example : ALL
+ : @test2 : ALL
+ : @example1 : ALL
+ : @test1 : ALL
+ : @test3 : ALL
```

I got a reply about how to merge the 2 files from this answer [Vladimir Botka_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73311329/insert-lines-in-a-file-from-an-other-file-lines-in-ansible). But what is causing an issue for me is the : `+ :` at the begining of each `<line>`, the filter must be applied after that if it starts with `@` or `alpha`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put *prefix* and *regex* into variables and test the first 5 characters. For example,

```yaml
    - name: insert line
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/test2
        line: "{{ item }}"
        insertafter: "{{ (item[0:5] == prefix)|ternary('EOF', omit) }}"
        insertbefore: "{{ (item[0:5] != prefix)|ternary(regex, omit) }}"
        firstmatch: true
      loop: "{{ tmp_content.stdout_lines }}"
      vars:
        prefix: '+ : @'
        regex: '^\+ \: @.*$'
```

gives

```
shell> cat /tmp/test2
+ : argument1.1 : ALL
+ : argument2192 : ALL
+ : argument1 : ALL
+ : argument2 : ALL
+ : @example : ALL
+ : @test2 : ALL
+ : @example1 : ALL
+ : @test1 : ALL
+ : @test3 : ALL
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: check test1 content
      command: cat /tmp/test1
      register: tmp_content
      changed_when: false
    - name: insert line
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/test2
        line: "{{ item }}"
        insertafter: "{{ (item[0:5] == prefix)|ternary('EOF', omit) }}"
        insertbefore: "{{ (item[0:5] != prefix)|ternary(regex, omit) }}"
        firstmatch: true
      loop: "{{ tmp_content.stdout_lines }}"
      vars:
        prefix: '+ : @'
        regex: '^\+ \: @.*$'
```

- The playbook is idempotent. See the output of the *diff_mode* below

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --diff
...
TASK [insert line] ****************************************
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 + : argument1.1 : ALL
 + : argument2192 : ALL
++ : argument1 : ALL
 + : @example : ALL
 + : @test2 : ALL
 + : @example1 : ALL

changed: [localhost] => (item=+ : argument1 : ALL)
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
 + : argument1.1 : ALL
 + : argument2192 : ALL
 + : argument1 : ALL
++ : argument2 : ALL
 + : @example : ALL
 + : @test2 : ALL
 + : @example1 : ALL

changed: [localhost] => (item=+ : argument2 : ALL)
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -5,3 +5,4 @@
 + : @example : ALL
 + : @test2 : ALL
 + : @example1 : ALL
++ : @test1 : ALL

changed: [localhost] => (item=+ : @test1 : ALL)
ok: [localhost] => (item=+ : @test2 : ALL)
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -6,3 +6,4 @@
 + : @test2 : ALL
 + : @example1 : ALL
 + : @test1 : ALL
++ : @test3 : ALL

changed: [localhost] => (item=+ : @test3 : ALL)
```

---

Q: ***" Add the lines containing `@` behind the last match line containing `@`."***

A: Use *regex* both in *insertafter* and *insertbefore*, and select *firstmatch* according the *prefix*. Technically, append `@` lines to the `@` block and prepend others. For example, given the file

```
shell> cat /tmp/test2
+ : argument1.1 : ALL
+ : argument2192 : ALL
+ : @example : ALL
+ : @test2 : ALL
+ : @example1 : ALL
+ : <rubish>
```

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - name: insert line
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/test2
        line: "{{ item }}"
        insertafter: "{{ (item[0:5] == prefix)|ternary(regex, omit) }}"
        insertbefore: "{{ (item[0:5] != prefix)|ternary(regex, omit) }}"
        firstmatch: "{{ (item[0:5] != prefix)|ternary(true, false) }}"
      loop: "{{ tmp_content.stdout_lines }}"
      vars:
        prefix: '+ : @'
        regex: '^\+ \: @.*$'
```

See the output of the diff_mode below

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --diff
...
TASK [insert line] ******************************************
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 + : argument1.1 : ALL
 + : argument2192 : ALL
++ : argument1 : ALL
 + : @example : ALL
 + : @test2 : ALL
 + : @example1 : ALL

changed: [localhost] => (item=+ : argument1 : ALL)
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
 + : argument1.1 : ALL
 + : argument2192 : ALL
 + : argument1 : ALL
++ : argument2 : ALL
 + : @example : ALL
 + : @test2 : ALL
 + : @example1 : ALL

changed: [localhost] => (item=+ : argument2 : ALL)
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -5,4 +5,5 @@
 + : @example : ALL
 + : @test2 : ALL
 + : @example1 : ALL
++ : @test1 : ALL
 + : <rubish>

changed: [localhost] => (item=+ : @test1 : ALL)
ok: [localhost] => (item=+ : @test2 : ALL)
--- before: /tmp/test2 (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test2 (content)
@@ -6,4 +6,5 @@
 + : @test2 : ALL
 + : @example1 : ALL
 + : @test1 : ALL
++ : @test3 : ALL
 + : <rubish>

changed: [localhost] => (item=+ : @test3 : ALL)
```

Comment: you are always amazing, there is only a problem that the lines containing the `@` were added at the end of the file not behind the last match line containing `@`

Comment: I added an example of how to fix it.

Comment: You are the best, this is what the playbook should look 1000000000000000 thanks